# What does this command do (find / -name gcc 2>/dev/null)?

Tags: command-line

What does the command `find / -name gcc 2>/dev/null` do?

Comment: http://explainshell.com/ is a great resource for such questions.

Comment: @edwinksl nice site! Bookmarked for future reference :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's break it up for better understanding:

```
find / -name gcc
```

searches through the root dir (the `/` dir, that contains `/etc`, `/home` and so forth) for a file with the name `gcc`. This search is done recursively, meaning subdirectories, sub-subdirectories and so on get searched as well.

The `>` operator redirects the output. In this case, `2>` redirects the output of the standard channel for error messages, `stderr`.

```
ls > the_list.txt # writes the output of ls to a file
ls 2> the_list.txt # writes the output of ls on stderr to a file
```

`/dev/null` is a pseudo device that basically throws away everything that gets written to it. You can use it if you have to write stuff *somewhere*, but basically just want it gone.

So `ls > /dev/null` means "redirect the output of ls to /dev/null", or just "don't bother me with the output". As above, `ls 2>/dev/null` sends what's written on `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

The complete command

```
find / -name gcc 2>/dev/null
```

therefore means "search on the whole system for a file called `gcc`, but don't show me any error messages that occur while doing so".